# Enable/Disable Buttons in Excel (Active X)

Tags: excel, vba, button, activex

My workbook has 2 sheets

- `MainSheet` for the buttons and serves as the main page
- `DataSheet` for the formula and data linked to what’s in sheet 1)

I have 3 groups of option buttons (each having 2 buttons) and a combo box containing 3 lines of data. The cell linked to the combo box is in `DataSheet`, A3 while the range is in B3:B5.

What I need is to

- enable Group 2 (buttons 3 & 4) and Group 3 (buttons 5 & 6) only if button 2 (Group 1) will be selected.
- Or whichever among the buttons 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 will be clicked first should enable the remaining mentioned buttons from the groups.
- But if button 1 (Group 1) will be selected, all buttons in Group 2 & 3 must be disabled, as well as the combo box.
- The same when any from the 3 contents of combo box will be selected, all the buttons from all the Groups must be disabled.

This is the only one I was able to correctly solved (I’m not sure about the combo box):

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
OptionButton1.Enabled = True
OptionButton3.Enabled = True
OptionButton4.Enabled = True
OptionButton5.Enabled = True
OptionButton6.Enabled = True
ComboBox1.Enabled = False

Else

OptionButton3.Enabled = False
OptionButton4.Enabled = False
OptionButton5.Enabled = False
OptionButton6.Enabled = False
ComboBox1.Enabled = False

End If
End Sub
```